# Problem for posting documents in solr core

Tags: solr

I'm indexing documents in solr core,but some documents are not indexing. I don't know that why these are not indexing.

When I am indexing a string and then the tokens of the string, 
then only the tokens are indexing but the whole text is not 
indexing. While if I index in reverse order that is : firstly the tokens of text and then text, so then the text will be index..

When I am indexing documents

```
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"कपड़ा धोने की 
मशीन","translated_text":"washing machine"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"कपड़ा","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"धोने","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"की","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"मशीन","translated_text":" 
"}
```

Then only 4 documents are indexing in solr core instead of 5 documents. And these 4 documents are `{कपड़ा ,धोने ,की,मशीन}`.

But when I am doing the indexing like:

```
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"कपड़ा","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"धोने","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"की","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"मशीन","translated_text":" 
"},
{"detected_language":"hi","searchstring":"कपड़ा धोने की 
मशीन","translated_text":"washing machine"}
```

Then all 5 documents will be indexing.

I have used these fields:

```xml
<field name="searchstring" type="string_hi" indexed="true" 
stored="true" required="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false" 
/>
<field name="detected_language" type="string"  indexed="true" 
stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false"/> 
<field name="translated_text" type="string"  indexed="true" 
stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

And the fieldType for searchstring is:

```xml
<fieldType name="string_hi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> 
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I expect that all the searchstring will be index..

Comment: What is your `uniqueKey` field? My initial guess is that you've set the `uniqueKey` field to a field type that is analyzed, so that `कपड़ा` in both strings ends up overwriting the previous one.

Comment: uniqueKey is searchstring.

Answer (score 1):

The `uniqueKey` of a document should never be an analyzed type - at least not one that ends up with multiple tokens (so no tokenizer except possibly `KeywordTokenizer`). You'll end up with issues where an existing document will be overwritten otherwise.

Create an `id` field as `string`, set it as the `uniqueKey` field, then use `copyField` to copy the content from `searchstring` into `id`.